# Node.js - Get the SchemaObject without querying?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, coffeescript, mongoose

Givem that I have the `Subdomain ID`, do I need to do a find in order to get the Subdomain object?

e.g: I have to do `Subdomain.find {_id: item.subdomain_id}, (err, subdomain) ->` in order to get the object subdomain? It'd be much better just to do `item.subdomain`.

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788013/node-js-document-returning-undefined-mongoose/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have the _id you're still going to have to look-up the document itself. In Mongoose this can be done with Model.findById as described here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/finding-documents.html#Model.findById